# How to calculate the permitted resultant states of 3 quadrupole phonons ($\ell=2$)?

Tags: condensed-matter, angular-momentum, phonons

How do i get the permitted resultant states of 3 quadrupole phonons ($\ell=2$)?

I think im supposed to somehow tabulate the $m$ states.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to repeatedly couple $\ell=2$ states.

Step 1 is to get the Clebsch-Gordan series: $2\otimes 2=4\oplus 3\oplus 2\oplus 1\oplus 0$ if there is no symmetry/antisymmetry restriction.  Next, couple $\ell=2$ again to this sum, i.e.
$2\otimes \left(4\oplus 3\oplus 2\oplus 1\oplus 0\right)$.  That's a lot of states: since the dimension of the irrep $\ell=2$ is $5$, you get $5\times 5\times 5=125$ states in total.  (Note that some final values of $L$ may appear more than once.)

If needed the step after is to actually construct the states.  For $L_{12}\in \{4,3, 2, 1, 0\}$ you first construct the states
$$
\vert L_{12}M_{12}\rangle =\sum_{m_1m_2} C^{L_{12}M_{12}}_{2m_1,2m_2}
\vert 2m_1\rangle\vert 2m_2\rangle\tag{1}
$$
with $C^{L_{12}M_{12}}_{2m_1,2m_2}$ a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient.

If $L_{123}$ is in $2\otimes \left(4\oplus 3\oplus 2\oplus 1\oplus 0\right)$, you then proceed with
$$
\vert L_{123}M_{123}\rangle =\sum_{m_{12}m_3} C^{L_{123}M_{123}}_{L_{12}m_{12},2m_3}
\vert L_{12}m_{12}\rangle\vert 3m_3\rangle
$$
where $\vert L_{12}m_{12}\rangle$ is as per (1).